# Priority of shapes that are added to a zone from a view

Tags: orchardcms

I'm not using Orchard terms here but I have a snippet of text that I want to wrap up in a shape. It's some social sharing urls on the blog detail page. I wanted to keep it clean so I decided to make a new shape.

I have posted the full listing of `Content-BlogPost.Detail.cshtml` below but the idea is that:

1. I make a `cshtml` to hold the social media markup
2. I prep the data in the main post detail view
3. I create the shape and add it to the `Meta` zone (which is a local zone not like meta descriptions) using `Model.Meta.Add(socialShape, "1");`

The shape is added as expected but the second parameter, the priority, doesn't work. It has to be a string, passing an `int` breaks the page. The default priority for the other items in the `Meta` zone are on 5 so it should put it at the top but it always ends up at the end.

```
// Model.Meta.Add works but the priority seems to be ignored?
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions
@using Orchard.Blogs.Models
@functions{
    void AddSocialMediaShareLinks() {
        var socialShareUrl = new Uri(new Uri(WorkContext.CurrentSite.BaseUrl), Url.ItemDisplayUrl((IContent)Model.ContentItem)).ToString();
        var socialShareTitle = Model.ContentItem.Title;
        var socialShape = New.BlogPost_SocialMediaShareLinks(ShareUrl: socialShareUrl, ShareTitle: socialShareTitle);
        Model.Meta.Add(socialShape, "1");
    }
}
@{
    if (Model.Title != null) {
        Layout.Title = Model.Title;
    }

    BlogPart parentBlog = Model.Blog;
    IContent contentItem = Model.ContentItem;
    var contentTypeClassName = ((string)Model.ContentItem.ContentType).HtmlClassify();

    AddSocialMediaShareLinks();

    Model.Classes.Add("content-item");
    Model.Classes.Add(contentTypeClassName);

    var tag = Tag(Model, "article");
}
@tag.StartElement
<header>
    @Display(Model.Header)
</header>
<div class="row row-blog-content">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        @if (Model.Meta != null) {
            <div class="metadata">
                @Display(Model.Meta)
            </div>
        }
        @Display(Model.Content)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-blog-return-parent">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <p class="text-center"><a href="@Url.ItemDisplayUrl(parentBlog)" class="btn btn-default">@T("Go back to the news")</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
@if (Model.Footer != null) {
    <footer>
        @Display(Model.Footer)
    </footer>
}
@tag.EndElement
```

After reading some articles I found old post be Bertrand post about [customizing the first item template](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/orchard-list-customization-first-item-template).

I thought maybe where I was adding it to the zone was too late in the process so I changed the code to the snippet below, but the `Model.Meta.Add` never gets hit in this scenario:

```
@functions{
    void AddSocialMediaShareLinks() {
        var socialShareUrl = new Uri(new Uri(WorkContext.CurrentSite.BaseUrl), Url.ItemDisplayUrl((IContent)Model.ContentItem)).ToString();
        var socialShareTitle = Model.ContentItem.Title;
        var socialShape = New.BlogPost_SocialMediaShareLinks(ShareUrl: socialShareUrl, ShareTitle: socialShareTitle);

        ShapeMetadata metadata = Model.Metadata;
        metadata.OnDisplaying(ctx => {
            Model.Meta.Add(socialShape, "1");
        });
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable ordering, you should add `Tab` property to the shape `Metadata`, as following:

```cs
socialShape.Metadata.Tab = "";
Model.Meta.Add(socialShape, "1");
```

This will disable shapes grouping within `ContentZone`.

I think it's a bug in Orchard, but this workaround should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct it is a bug. With your help I've tracked it down enough to open an issue at least, couldn't quite figure out where it was going wrong though: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/7258

Comment: This bug will be resolved in the next release of Orchard. Thanks for your help diagnosing it. https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/pull/7321

Answer (score 1):

Most shapes just render their children in the order they were added. The difference in `Zone` and `ContentZone` shapes is the call to `Order` before the children are rendered:

```
    [Shape]
    public void Zone(dynamic Display, dynamic Shape, TextWriter Output) {
        string id = Shape.Id;
        IEnumerable<string> classes = Shape.Classes;
        IDictionary<string, string> attributes = Shape.Attributes;
        var zoneWrapper = GetTagBuilder("div", id, classes, attributes);
        Output.Write(zoneWrapper.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        foreach (var item in Order(Shape))
            Output.Write(Display(item));
        Output.Write(zoneWrapper.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
    }
```

You can get the same effect in your own shapes by also calling `Order` from your template or shape method code.

Comment: 'ContentZone' also call 'Order' method to order child shapes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, your help directed me into the right method to diagnose that this is in fact a bug: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/7258